# What is the step called when you switch out the absolute value for a plus or minus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

When running algebra problems for an intro algebra class, students are often asked to name what happened in each step.

So what is the name of the step when you do something like this?

Given.
$$ \lvert x-2 \rvert =10$$
Mystery step.
$$ x-2 =\pm 10 $$

What is this mystery step called?  Does it have a name?

Comment: It's really an analysis of cases. If $x-2\geq 0$, then $|x-2|=x-2$, so you get $x-2=10$. If $x-2\lt 0$, then $|x-2|=-(x-2)$, so you get $-(x-2)=10$, or $x-2=-10$. Alternatively, it's an application of a theorem that says that for $b\geq 0$, $|a|=b$ if and only if $a=10$ or $a=-10$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called "sloppy notation".

Seriously, though: writing "$x-2=\pm 10$" is really shorthand for
"$x-2 = 10$ or $x-2 = -10$". It's a disjunction of two statements.

The equivalence is correct because $10$ and $-10$ are the only numbers whose absolute value is $10$, so if an expression has $10$ as its absolute value, then the either expression must equal $10$ or the expression must equal $-10$. Voila.